# How to solve Error: Command failed: npm install while installing gatsby starter theme

Tags: gatsby

I am trying to install a gatsby starter theme on my project directory, but instead I am getting this error message which I don't really know how to tackle.
Error message:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQyQS.jpg)

> Command failed: npm install
> Error: Command failed: npm install
>
> - index.js:236 Promise.all.then.arr
>   [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:236:11
> - next_tick.js:68 process._tickCallback
>   internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7

Comment: Please do not put code as images, post code blocks instead.

Comment: i'm new here, will get it corrected next time

Comment: You should get it corrected this time. When ever you ask question it get indexed and later it might be used by somebody else who has same problem. If you image link dies, this topic won't help.

Comment: it's corrected already

Comment: so, what have you tried so far? did you even install moment? how did you do that?

Comment: npm install bulma
i believe the moment comes with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested it on my mac and had no issues running npm install.

So I guess it has nothing to do with Gatsby itself. Your NodeJS version might be a bit older than the current version v12.7.0. I'm running v12.6.0 so I would recommend you to upgrade NodeJS and try it again.